# SOLVED: cakephp 5.0.2 : cake bake with limited options

Tags: cakephp

With cakephp 5.0.2 I cannot bake code, 'cake bake' return the error below

Did I miss something ? This application has been migrated from cakephp 4.5 release.

```
bin/cake bake
Unknown command `cake bake`. Run `cake --help` to get the list of commands.
Did you mean: `bake policy`?

Other valid choices:

- help
- version
- cleaner
- console
- relance
- i18n
- routes
- server
- benchmark
- bake policy
```

With just bin/cake :

```
bin/cake
```

*No command provided. Choose one of the available commands.

Current Paths:

- app:  src/
- root: /opt/applications/p35/
- core: /opt/applications/p35/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/

Available Commands:

App:

- cleaner
- console
- help
- relance
- relance_epreuves
- resultat

Authorization:

- bake policy

CakePHP:

- cache clear
- cache clear_all
- cache clear_group
- cache list
- completion
- i18n
- i18n extract
- i18n init
- plugin assets copy
- plugin assets remove
- plugin assets symlink
- plugin load
- plugin loaded
- plugin unload
- routes
- routes check
- routes generate
- schema_cache build
- schema_cache clear
- server
- version

DebugKit:

- benchmark

To run a command, type `cake command_name [args|options]`
To get help on a specific command, type `cake command_name --help`

Comment: Looks like what would happen when the bake plugin hasn't been loaded. https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/plugins.html#loading-a-plugin

Comment: Yes correct! Bake is not loaded
bin/cake plugin load Bake solve the problem 
Thanks @ndm

Answer (score 0):

Bake plugin was not loaded

```
bin/cake plugin load Bake
```

solved the problem
Thank @ndm